# How to make an array empty in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub WriteToZeroBasedArray()

Dim E As Integer
Dim rCount As Long: rCount = 

Worksheets("0618").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
For E = 9 To rCount


Dim V() As Variant ' Note the parentheses!
Dim P() As Variant
Dim N() As Variant
Dim Index As Long
Dim Index_2 As Long
Dim Index_3 As Long
Dim cCount As Long: cCount = Worksheets("0618").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column ' e.g.

Dim c As Long '배열에 값 저장하기
For c = 7 To cCount
    If 0 < Worksheets("0618").Cells(E, c).Value And Worksheets("0618").Cells(E, c).Value < 100 Then
        ReDim Preserve V(Index)
        ' A safer way (Option Base related):
        'ReDim Preserve V(0 To Index)
        V(Index) = Worksheets("0618").Cells(2, c).Value
        Index = Index + 1
        
        ReDim Preserve P(Index_2)
        P(Index_2) = Worksheets("0618").Cells(4, c).Value
        Index_2 = Index_2 + 1
        
        ReDim Preserve N(Index_3)
        N(Index_3) = Worksheets("0618").Cells(E, c).Value
        Index_3 = Index_3 + 1
    End If
Next c

 
Dim K As Integer
Dim L As Integer

K = UBound(V)  '배열의 값 차례로 Sheet2에 넣기
For L = 0 To K
  If L < 5 Then
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(L + 6 + 14 * (E - 9), 1).Value = V(L)
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(L + 6 + 14 * (E - 9), 2).Value = P(L)
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(L + 6 + 14 * (E - 9), 3).Value = N(L)
  Else
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(L + 1 + 14 * (E - 9), 5).Value = V(L)
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(L + 1 + 14 * (E - 9), 6).Value = P(L)
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(L + 1 + 14 * (E - 9), 7).Value = N(L)
  End If
    
Next

Dim FP As Integer
Dim Sum As Integer
  Sum = 0
'수량*단가 구하기
For FP = (6 + 14 * (E - 9)) To (10 + 14 * (E - 9))
  Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 4).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 2).Value * Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 3).Value
  Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 8).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 6).Value * Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 7).Value
  
  '총액 구하기
  Sum = Sum + Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 4).Value + Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 8).Value
  
  '0 지우기
  If Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 4).Value = 0 Then
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 4).ClearContents
  End If
  If Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 8).Value = 0 Then
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(FP, 8).ClearContents
  End If
Next

'총액 구하기2
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(12 + 14 * (E - 9), 8).Value = Sum

'받으실 분
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(3 + 14 * (E - 9), 2).Value = Worksheets("0618").Cells(E, 3).Value

'주소
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(3 + 14 * (E - 9), 5).Value = Worksheets("0618").Cells(E, 2).Value

'서식 복사'
Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1:H13").Copy
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & 15 + 14 * (E - 9)).PasteSpecial

Erase V, P, N
If Index = 0 Then Exit Sub

Next

Debug.Print Join(V, vbLf)



End Sub
```

I used "Erase V, P, N" at the last part of this code to make V,P,N into empty arrays, because the code has to repeat from E = 9 to E = Column number and as it repeats, these arrays has to be continuously empty at the last part of the code, to use them again at the next repeat.
But when I run this code, these arrays doesn't become empty. The values are accumulated more and more as the code repeats. I think maybe the code "Erase V, P, N" is the wrong code.
So Could anybody please tell me how to make the the arrays empty?

Comment: @freeflow re _The erase statement will set each item in the array to empty._ no, it won't.  That would be true if `V`, `P` and `N` were fixied size arrays.  In the OP's code thry are Dynamic arrays, therefore thre are reinitialised to unassigned arrays (observe them in the watch window after `Erase`, as `variant/Variant()`)  see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/erase-statement)

Comment: @김다영 no repo.  For me, `Erase` correctly reinitialises the variables